# Is a mass interruption a standard procedure in case of a supposed Eucharistic miracle?

Tags: catholicism, communion, miracles, mass, canon-law

I have read several stories about Eucharistic miracles and it seems the mass is always interrupted on such event. Is it a standard procedure (as for 4th June 2018) or is it up to the priest?

More broadly: what is the standard procedure in case an supposed (not confirmed yet) Eucharistic miracle happens during a mass?

The question differs from [In a Eucharistic miracle, do the communicants still partake of the sacrament?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37240/in-a-eucharistic-miracle-do-the-communicants-still-partake-of-the-sacrament) as there are often many Hosts left [with Christ presence not affected](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52909/40341) and the postulated duplicate is specifically about partaking of the affected Hosts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a Eucharistic miracle, do the communicants still partake of the sacrament?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37240/in-a-eucharistic-miracle-do-the-communicants-still-partake-of-the-sacrament)

Comment: @AndrewLeach please see the edit

Comment: If you're going to edit your question, please make it complete; don't chop it up with "{Edit}" flags. The previous history is always available. If there are "many kinds of eucharistic miracle", then there are many answers and this question is too broad: you will need to qualify what kind of miracle you're talking about — generally a "eucharistic miracle" is that the accidents are changed.

Comment: Well, I can't change my close vote. I still reckon this is a duplicate, but if it's not then it's too broad. I'm certainly not going to withdraw that vote.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I have narrowed the scope of the question. I guess you are probably right as all cases mentioning the interruption explicitly I remember were about accidents change.